# Changing complex JSON files to .csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I've downloaded a JSON file with lots of data about football players and I want to get at the data in a .csv. I'm a newb at most of this!

You can find the raw file here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llimllib/fantasypl_stats/8ba3e796fc3e73c43921da44d4344c08ce1d7031/data/players.1440000356.json

In the past I've used this code to export some of the data into a .csv using some python code (I think!) in command prompt:

```
import csv
import json

json_data = open("file.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

f = csv.writer(open("fix_hists.csv","wb+"))

arr = []

    for i in data:
    fh = data[i]["fixture_history"]
    array = fh["all"]
    for j in array:

        try:
            j.insert(0,str(data[i]["first_name"]))
        except:
            j.insert(0,'error')

        try:
            j.insert(1,data[i]["web_name"])
        except:
            j.insert(1,'error')

        try:
            f.writerow(j)
        except:
            f.writerow(['error','error'])

json_data.close()
```

Sadly, when I do this now in command prompt, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): <br/>
 File"fix_hist.py", line 12 (module) <br/>
  fh = data[i]["fixture_history"] <br/>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Can this be fixed or is there another way I can grab some of the data and convert it to .csv? Specifically the 'Fixture History'? and then 'First'Name', 'type_name' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's an improper tab on the `for` loop on line 11. if you update your code to look like the following, it should run without errors

```
import csv
import json

json_data = open("players.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

f = csv.writer(open("fix_hists.csv","wb+"))

arr = []

for i in data:
    fh = data[i]["fixture_history"]
    array = fh["all"]
    for j in array:

        try:
            j.insert(0,str(data[i]["first_name"]))
        except:
            j.insert(0,'error')

        try:
            j.insert(1,data[i]["web_name"])
        except:
            j.insert(1,'error')

        try:
            f.writerow(j)
        except:
            f.writerow(['error','error'])

json_data.close()
```

make sure that you've named the JSON file `players.json` to match the name on line 4. also, make sure that the JSON file and this python file are in the same directory. you can run the python file in a development environment like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), or you can `cd` to the directory in a terminal/command prompt window and run it with `python fileName.py`. it will create a csv file in that directory called `fix_hists.csv`

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using pandas.

Pandas has a function for parsing JSON files. **pd.read_json()**

docs:   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

This will read the JSON file directly into a dataframe

Comment: Thanks,

I'm a newn!

What do I type and where?!

Comment: well first you'll  have to install the pandas library using  `pip install pandas`

Comment: then simply import pandas and type the command `pandas.read_json(url)` this wont perfectly solve the problem but you can then look at how pandas is storing the file in a tabular data form and then if it looks correct you can use `to_csv(path)` to save it as a csv

Comment: Thanks, I have Anaconda and use ipython notebook which has Pandas apparently. I typed in the pandas.read bit above and it says there is a syntax error?

Comment: `import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llimllib/fantasypl_stats/8ba3e796fc3e73c43921da44d4344c08ce1d7031/data/players.1440000356.json")`